# MySQL how to ignore indexig while inserting rows

Tags: mysql, insert, indexing, bulkinsert

I have a table in my MySQL database with round 5M rows. Inserting rows to the table is too slow as MySQL updates index while inserting. How to stop index updating while inserting and do the indexing separately later?

Thanks
Kamrul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your table might be over indexed. Maybe post your table definition here so we can have a look.

You have two choices:

1. Keep current indexes and remove unused indexes. If you have 3 indexes on a table for every single write to the table there will be 3 writes to the indexes. A index is only helpful during reads so you might want to remove unused indexes. During a load indexes will be updated which will slow down your load.
2. Drop you indexes before load then recreate them after load. You can drop your indexes before data load then insert and rebuild. The rebuild might take longer than the slow inserts. You will have to rebuild all indexes one by one. Also unique indexes can fail if duplicates are loaded during the load process without the indexes.

Now I suggest you take a good look at the indexes on the table and reduce them if they are not used in any queries. Then try both approaches and see what works for you. There is no way I know of in MySQL to disable indexes as they need the values insert to be written to their internal structures.

Another thing you might want to try it to split the IO over multiple drives i.e partition your table over several drives to get some hardware performance in place.